# Error in Dropdown list with QUERY, IF Formula in Google Sheet, can anyone Correct?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The post with this named QUERY AND DROPDOWN FILTER FORMULA IN GOOGLE SHEET  was shared earlier. But the code that was given in it was completely changed and another code was given to make it ready. I don't understand all that code. I'm just learning Google Sheets. So I am sharing another post. I have put the easy to understand code in it. It is getting results (A2 CELL, ALL WARD LICENSE APPLICATION, WARD 1 LICENSE APPLICATION, WARD 2 LICENSE APPLICATIONS ETC…. But the code given by the column FOR A3, ALL APPLICATIONS, ALL NEW LICENSE APPLICATIONS, ALL RENEWAL LICENSE APPLICATIONS ETC does not get the result. Can you fix the above code (A2 CODE, CONTAINS FORMULA ETC) without completely changing everything. You can add the required code to it LIKE. PL HELP ME. ITS my job work matter

MY GOOGLE SHEET LINK BELOW.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nJ7SOStcnt-xz9JVVahoBKPfLGC0OcjvFog9g9L9dRc/edit?usp=sharing

MY CODE

```
=IF(A2="ALL WARD LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
  QUERY(ALL!B3:K,"SELECT * "),
 IF(A2="WARD 1 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 01/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 2 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 02/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 3 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 03/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 4 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 04/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 5 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 05/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 6 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 06/' "),
```

ABOVE CODE FOR A2 COLUMN WORKING...

BELOW CODE FOR A3 COLUMN NOT WORKING, CAN ANYONE CORRECT BELOW ????

```
IF(A3="ALL APPLICATIONS", 
  QUERY(ALL!B3:K,"SELECT * "),

 IF(A3="ALL NEW LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE H CONTAINS 'NEW LICENSE APPLICATION' "),

IF(A3="ALL RENEWAL LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
      QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
            "SELECT * WHERE H CONTAINS 'RENEWAL LICENSE APPLICATIONS' "),

IF(A3="FEE NOT PAIND", 
      QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
            "SELECT * WHERE K CONTAINS 'FEE PENDING' "),
)))))))))))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nJ7SOStcnt-xz9JVVahoBKPfLGC0OcjvFog9g9L9dRc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you trying to use both `A2` and `A3` to where condition of `QUERY()` function.

Comment: See my answer as well as your sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use lookup tables for conditions. See `Conditions` sheet in your workbook. Then use below formula-

```
=QUERY(ALL!A3:K,"where D like '" & 
XLOOKUP(A2,Conditions!A1:A7,Conditions!B1:B7) & "%' AND" & IF(A3="FEE NOT PAID"," K like '"," H like '") & 
XLOOKUP(A3,Conditions!D1:D4,Conditions!E1:E4) & "%'",0)
```

[image]